# Thread won't resume after multithreaded session

Tags: c#, multithreading, parallel.foreach

I have a thread, call it the "Parsing thread".

```
Thread parsingThread = new Thread(myMethod);
```

I perform some computations on this thread, of which the last involves more parallel computations.

```
    public void ReadCityFiles(BlockingCollection<GeonamesFileInfo> files)
    {
        Parallel.ForEach<GeonamesFileInfo>(
            files.GetConsumingPartitioner<GeonamesFileInfo>(),
            new ParallelOptions { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = _maxParallelism },
            (inputFile, args) =>
            {
                RaiseFileParsing(inputFile);
                using (var input = new System.IO.StreamReader(inputFile.FullName))
                {
                    while (!input.EndOfStream)
                    {
                        RaiseEntryParsed(ParseCity(input.ReadLine()));
                        Interlocked.Increment(ref _parsedEntries);
                    }
                }
                RaiseFileParsed(inputFile);
            });
        RaiseDirectoryParsed(Directory);
    }
```

The problem is that when these very long and computationally expensive async foreach operations finish (~30 mins), the "Parsing Thread" doesn't resume. My GUI is still responsive, but the RaiseDirectoryParsed function that is supposed to continue to run on the "Parsing Thread" is never called. I debugged the program up to this point, and am pretty baffled as to what to do in this situation.

Comment: What does RaiseDirectoryParsed do and what does the "parsing thread" do?

Comment: Most likely on of the `Parellel.ForEach` tasks does not terminate properly. Have you used some console messages to determine this?

Comment: Raises an event handled by the parsing thread. It never runs anyway, execution stops after the parallel.foreach, as if the parsing thread never resumes or something.

Comment: Tudor, good point. How can I check this if the task's stack traces show up as external code?

Comment: @Francisco Aguilera: Just put a `Console.WriteLine` at the end of the task code. See if all the tasks terminate eventually. My guess is they won't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The point of `BlockingCollection` is that when an operation cannot be performed now, but might be in the future (e.g. `Take()` or `Add()` on a collection with bounded capacity), it will block. The same applies to `GetConsumingEnumerable()` and thus also to `GetConsumingPartitioner()`: if the collection is currently empty, the enumerable will block until you add more items to the collection.

But there is also a way to tell the collection that you're not going to add new items anymore and that it shouldn't block when empty from now on: [the `CompleteAdding()` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd287086). If you call this when you know you won't be adding any more new items to the collection, your `Parallel.ForEach()` won't block anymore and your thread will continue executing.

Comment: Thank you for your observation, however, I have called CompleteAdding(), and I verified that the collection's isComplete field is true. What could be the issue?